# Reproducing Ramond's sunset diagram calculation for $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, regularization

I am unable to reproduce the calculation of the sunset diagram for $\phi^4$ theory in Pierre Ramond's Fied Theory a Modern Primer. This is the second edition chapter 4.4. He starts with eq. (4.4.19)
\begin{equation}
\Sigma(p) = \frac{\lambda^2 (\mu^2)^{4-2\omega}}{6} \int \frac{d^{2\omega}\ell}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}} \frac{d^{2\omega}q}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}} \frac{1}{\ell^2+m^2} \frac{1}{q^2+m^2} \frac{1}{(q+p-\ell)^2+m^2}
\end{equation}
He introduces 1 in the form
\begin{equation}
1=\frac{1}{4\omega}\left[ \frac{\partial \ell_\mu}{ \partial \ell_\mu}+ \frac{\partial q_\mu}{ \partial q_\mu}\right]
\end{equation}
to get
\begin{equation}
\Sigma(p) = \frac{\lambda^2 (\mu^2)^{4-2\omega}}{6} \int \frac{d^{2\omega}\ell}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}} \frac{d^{2\omega}q}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}}\frac{1}{4\omega}\left[ \frac{\partial \ell_\mu}{ \partial \ell_\mu}+ \frac{\partial q_\mu}{ \partial q_\mu}\right] \frac{1}{\ell^2+m^2} \frac{1}{q^2+m^2} \frac{1}{(q+p-\ell)^2+m^2}
\end{equation}
then uses partial integration and discards the boundary terms to get
\begin{equation}
\Sigma(p) = -\frac{\lambda^2 (\mu^2)^{4-2\omega}}{6} \times\\ \int \frac{d^{2\omega}\ell}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}} \frac{d^{2\omega}}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}}\frac{1}{4\omega}\left[  \ell_\mu\frac{\partial}{ \partial \ell_\mu}+  q_\mu \frac{\partial}{ \partial q_\mu}\right] \frac{1}{\ell^2+m^2} \frac{1}{q^2+m^2} \frac{1}{(q+p-\ell)^2+m^2}\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
All of that is fine, but then he says that explicit differentiation gives the result
\begin{equation}
\Sigma(p) = \frac{1}{2\omega-3}\frac{\lambda^2 (\mu^2)^{4-2\omega}}{6}\int \frac{d^{2\omega}\ell}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}} \frac{d^{2\omega}q}{(2\pi)^{2\omega}}\frac{3 m^2 + p\cdot(p+q-\ell)} {(\ell^2+m^2) (q^2+m^2) [(q+p-\ell)^2+m^2]^2}
\end{equation}
I cannot find how to reproduce this formula. In fact I do not understand how the coefficient $1/\omega$ disappears and the coefficient $1/(2\omega-3)$ can appear.
Indeed, for general momenta $\ell$ and $k$
\begin{equation}
 \ell_\mu\frac{\partial}{ \partial \ell_\mu} \frac{1}{(k-\ell)^2+ m^2} = \frac{2\ell\cdot (k-\ell)}{[(k-\ell)^2+ m^2]^2} 
 \end{equation}
 When you use this into (1) you only get inner products of momenta. Without having to do the calculation in detail, how can the dimension (dis)appear in the computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, it is the 't Hooft Veltman regularisation scheme explained 5-6 pages earlier. I guess that's what happens when you start reading a section in the middle of the book.

Answer (score 3):

$$
   I(p)=\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]}.
$$

$$
   I(p)=-\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{2D}(p_1^\mu\frac{\partial  }{p_1^\mu}+p_2^\mu\frac{\partial  }{p_2^\mu})\frac{1}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]}.
$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
 I(p)&=&  \frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{p_1^2}{(p_1^2+m^2)^2(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]}\\
 && \frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{p_1(p+p_1+p_2)}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]^2}\\
 && \frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{p_1^2}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)^2[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]}\\
 && \frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{p_2(p+p_1+p_2)}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]^2}\\
 &=& \frac{3}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{1}{(p_1^2+m^2) (p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]}\\
 &&-\frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{m^2}{(p_1^2+m^2)^2 (p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]} \\
 &&-\frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{m^2}{(p_1^2+m^2) (p_2+m^2)^2[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]} \\
 &&-\frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{m^2}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]^2 } \\
 &&-\frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{p (p+p_1+p_2)}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]^2}\\
 &=& \frac{3}{D} I(p) - \frac{1}{D}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{3m^2+p (p+p_1+p_2)}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

$$I(p)= -\frac{1}{D-3}\int\frac{d^D p_1}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dp_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{3m^2+p (p+p_1+p_2)}{(p_1^2+m^2)(p_2+m^2)[(p+p_1+p_2)^2+m^2]^2}$$